# Binding Generic Repository and Specific Repository with Ninject 2.2

Tags: repository, ninject, ninject-2

I have a IRepository that I have implemented in Repository and I extended Repository for specific type as UsersRepository I need to bind all types using the generic binding for Ninject however when requesting instance for IRepository I need to get UsersRepository instead of Repository.

```
Bind<IDbContext>().To<SMSDataContext>()
.WithConstructorArgument("connectionStringName", "dbcsname");
```

Here I am binding the generic repository:

```
Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>))
.WithConstructorArgument("dbContext",new SMSDataContext("dbcsname"));
```

Here I am trying to bind a specific instance:

```
Bind<IRepository<Setting>>().ToConstant(settingsRepository);
```

Tried different approaches with ".ToConstant" and with only ".To" also tried to bind to concrete implementation like follows:

```
 UsersRepository usersRepository = new UsersRepository(new SMSDataContext("SMSDB"));
 Bind<IRepository<Setting>>().To<SettingsRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("dbContext", new SMSDataContext("dbscname")); ;
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it is only possible using some cheat because open generic bindings have the same priority as closed generic bindings. But you can increase the priority of a binding by adding a condition.

```
Bind<IRepository<Setting>>().ToConstant(settingsRepository).When(ctx => true);
```

Comment: Thanks that actually works however it seems like i must defined that i am expecting instance of SettingRepository as follows:

`var rep = Container.Resolve<IRepository<Setting>>() as SettingsRepository;`

Thanks again.

Comment: ToConstructor was just an example as it was the first occurance in your code. You can also use To<SettingsRepository>()

Comment: Yes, managed to get this working much cleaner now :) Thanks again.